# PIG: Get all tuples out of a grouped bag

Tags: apache-pig

I am using PIG to generate groups from tuples as follows:

```
a1, b1
a1, b2
a1, b3
...

->

a1, [b1, b2, b3]
...
```

This is easy and working. But my problem is to get the following: From the obtained groups, I would like to generate a set of all tuples in the group's bag:

```
a1, [b1, b2, b3]

->

b1,b2
b1,b3
b2,b3
```

This would be easy if I could nest "foreach" and firstly iterate over each group and then over its bag.

I suppose I am misunderstanding the concept and I will appreciate your explanation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like you need a Cartesian product between the bag and itself. To do this you need to use FLATTEN(bag) twice.

**Code:**

```
inpt = load '.../group.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (id, val);
grp = group inpt by (id);
id_grp = foreach grp generate group as id, inpt.val as value_bag;
result = foreach id_grp generate id, FLATTEN(value_bag) as v1, FLATTEN(value_bag) as v2; 
dump result;
```

Be aware that large bags will produce a lot of rows. To avoid it you could use TOP(...) before FLATTEN:

```
inpt = load '....group.txt' using PigStorage(',')  as (id, val);
grp = group inpt by (id);
id_grp = foreach grp generate group as id, inpt.val as values;
result = foreach id_grp {
    limited_bag = TOP(50, 0, values); -- all sorts of filtering could be done here
    generate id, FLATTEN(limited_bag) as v1, FLATTEN(limited_bag) as v2; 
};
dump result;
```

For your specific output you could use some filtering before FLATTEN:

```
inpt = load '..../group.txt' as (id, val);
grp = group inpt by (id);
id_grp = foreach grp generate group as id, inpt.val as values;
result = foreach id_grp {
    l = filter values by val == 'b1' or val == 'b2';
    generate id, FLATTEN(l) as v1, FLATTEN(values) as v2; 
};
result = filter result by v1 != v2;
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Also relevant is this [UnorderedPairs](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/UnorderedPairs.html) function from the [DataFu](http://datafu.org) UDF library. It generates pairs of all items in a bag (in your case your grouped bag)

Comment: Laurens is right.  This UDF does exactly what you need and it is also way more efficient than a pure Pig based solution using Cartesian product.  By the way, the URL has changed: [UnorderedPairs](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/UnorderedPairs.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GROUP ALL` pig statement to generate

```
A  = -- Some bag
B  = -- Another bag

groupedB = group B ALL;
result   = foreach A GENERATE 
    TOTUPLE(*), groupedB.$1;

-- Will generate
((a1), {(b1, b2, b3)})
((a2), {(b1, b2, b3)})
((a3), {(b1, b2, b3)})
...
```