# apache pig, permutations of values grouped by id

Tags: apache-pig, permutation

Using Apache Pig, I need all permutations of a field, grouped by an id field ('title' in this case).  The input data looks like this:

schema is {chararray, chararray}

```
(title1, name1)
(title1, name2)
(title1, name3)
(title2, name4)
(title2, name5)
(title2, name6)
```

I need all permutations of title1 name relations and title2 name relations in one list.  Desired output is:

```
(name1, name2)
(name1, name3)
(name2, name3)
(name4, name5)
(name4, name6)
(name5, name6)
```

I found this related answer [How To Find All Possible Permutations From A Bag under apache pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408179/how-to-find-all-possible-permutations-from-a-bag-under-apache-pig), but I'm having difficulties with extending the solution so that it limits the permutations for each title field.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more searching, using these two posts:
[How To Find All Possible Permutations From A Bag under apache pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25408179/how-to-find-all-possible-permutations-from-a-bag-under-apache-pig) , [PIG: Get all tuples out of a grouped bag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308050/pig-get-all-tuples-out-of-a-grouped-bag) led me to this solution:

input schema is {chararray, chararray}

```
inpt = foreach input generate $0 as (id:chararray), $1 as (val);
grp = group inpt by (id);
id_grp = foreach grp generate group as id, inpt.val as value_bag;
result = foreach id_grp generate FLATTEN(value_bag) as v1,FLATTEN(value_bag) as v2; 
result = filter result by v1 <= v2;
result = filter result by v1 != v2;
```